# How to kill a bash script as well as the python program started within the bash script?

Tags: python, bash, kill-process

I use `nohup` and bash scripts to help manage my python programs running on a local server. I have a bash script (`tmp.sh`) to invoke several python programs in a row. I try to kill the bash script and the python scripts started within the bash script with `kill $PID`, where `PID` is the process ID of the command `nohup bash tmp.sh &`, but only the bash script is terminated, and the python script keeps running. I don't want to export the process IDs of those python scripts because the bash script will run multiple python scripts within it and in that case I have to export the process ID of each python script.

I have created an example to reproduce the problem I have encountered.

Basically, I usually start my program by `source run2.sh`, which first determines if the same program is currently running to avoid duplicated running, and if not, submit a new job and change the `PID` to the new job in `~/.bashrc`.

`run2.sh`

```bash
submit_a_job()
{
    nohup bash tmp.sh &
    export PID=$! # get the process ID of the above submitted job
    echo "job $PID submitted at $(date)"
    echo "job $PID submitted at $(date)" >> output.log
    echo "export PID=$!" >> ~/.bashrc
}

if [ -n "$PID" ]; then
# PID set, safe to run any job
    if ps -p $PID > /dev/null; then
    # the job is still running
        echo "$PID is running, new job not submitted"
    else
    # the job has finished, delete previous PID, and submit a new job
        echo "$PID is finished, new job submitted"
        sed -i '/PID/d' ~/.bashrc
        submit_a_job
    fi
else
# PID not set, the job might still be running or have finished
    echo "helloworld"
    submit_a_job
fi
```

If you do not want to modify `~/.bashrc`, you can comment off the following lines in `run2.sh`. And make sure you run `run2.sh` with `source`, otherwise the environment variable is not exported to the current working shell.

```bash
echo "export PID=$!" >> ~/.bashrc
sed -i '/PID/d' ~/.bashrc
```

`tmp.sh` is the script that runs python jobs

```bash
time python3 while.py
```

`while.py` is just a meaningless dead loop

```py
import time

counter = 0

while True:
    print(f"This is an infinite loop! Iteration: {counter}", flush=True)
    counter += 1
    time.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second between iterations
```

As I have exported the ID of the process that runs `bash tmp.sh` as `PID`, I can kill the bash script `tmp.sh` with command `kill $PID`. The problem is, even if `tmp.sh` no longer runs, the python script that runs at the time I kill `tmp.sh` keeps running in the background. I can confirm this point by command `ps aux | grep python3`, which clearly indicates `while.py` is running.

Which command should I use to kill the bash script `tmp.sh` as well as the python program running at the same time I kill `tmp.sh`?

Comment: Kill the whole process group by negating the PID of the script.

Comment: `kill -INT -$PID`

Comment: Why does your script modify `.bashrc`?

Comment: I'm using echo "export PID=$!" >> ~/.bashrc to store PID. I hope to access PID after I log out.

Comment: Why not just use `pkill tmp.sh`?

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! I first use PID as a way to determine if my program is still running or not. Sometimes I submit a wrong job that I want to terminate midway and my first thought is to use PID.

Comment: Does my above `kill` command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the whole process group, rather than just the shell process.

```
kill -INT -$PID
```

When you give a negative PID to `kill`, it treats it as a process group ID.